# React: Cannot Find module './WebpackMissingModule'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm currently giving my first steps on React and I'm having some issues when trying to export components.

My current index.js file is as following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';

const API_KEY = '...';

//Create a new component. It should output some html
const App = function(){
    return <div>
        <SearchBar />
    </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

And my search_bar.js file:

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchBar = function(){
    return <input />;
};

export default SearchBar;
```

My current file structure may be seen in the following image:

[image]

The problem is that I'm not being able to import the SearchBar element. I'm having the error that can be seen on the image:

```
Cannot Find module './WebpackMissingModule'
```

Any idea on what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was baffled by this too, but refreshing the browser fixed for me.